# how to place text to the center over image with reponsive

Tags: html, css, image

[image]

below I have attached the image.

It has two images:
1) User profile image

2) The score board (below the user image)

Name and location should be placed over the scoreboard in centre , it should be responsive. 
Can you guys help me with this..

some how i made it look like this
attached the image below with the code

```css
.bdgframe { position: relative; margin-top: -40px; align-items: center; } .bdgprofile { width: 50%; } –
```

```html
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3" align="center">
    <img src="images4/pic_usr.png" class="img-responsive bdgprofile" />
    <img src="images4/frame.png" class="img-responsive bdgframe" />            
    <div>
    <p>ANKUR</p>
    <p>PARIS</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

attached fiddle  : https://jsfiddle.net/prabashanash/ggu91yjc/4/#&togetherjs=ifPxlavLH7

could u guys help me with tis ....

Comment: Where is your css?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: css :  .bdgframe {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -40px;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .bdgprofile {
            width: 50%;
        }

Comment: put the code in Question not comment, and use absolute path for image, we cannot see them like that

Comment: Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/prabashanash/ggu91yjc/4/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Think this is what you are looking for**

```
<style type="text/css">

.position{
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, 0%);
  text-align: center;

}
.fixed-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 83%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.location{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;

}
</style>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 position">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sqhz.png" />           
<div class="fixed-text">
<p>ANKUR</p>
<p class="location">PARIS</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks liamm12 > https://jsfiddle.net/prabashanash/ggu91yjc/5/

finally got it resopnsive

Comment: You're welcome here's my JSfiddile link, it looks better: http://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/gwgr4huo/

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming 1 & 2 Are same size images
- Assuming 2 is .png image

[image]

Then, (Used jquery)

```js
jQuery('.image').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/582e4337414fb5594a0cc385/58d6e32a8419c267b72d85f6/58d6e34ee6f2e12e70fb01a8/1491412293831/SexualHealth.png?format=300w" class="png-over" />')

});
```

```css
.image {
  position: relative
}

.png-over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/310x310" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>ANKUR</p>
    <p>PARIS</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Change `bottom : %` values as per your requirements

```css
 .bdgframe, .text {position:absolute; bottom:30%;margin:auto;left:0;right:0;}
 
 .bdgprofile { width: 50%;position:relative;}
 .text{bottom:18%;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3" align="center">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x300/wheat/wheat" class="img-responsive bdgprofile" />
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x30/fff/fff" class="img-responsive bdgframe" />            
<div class="text">
<p>ANKUR</p>
<p>PARIS</p>
</div>
</div>
```